# Getting a position of an element in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm building a a turn based board game which needs to contain 2 player that can move across the map. I'm stuck at getting the position of the player(which is just a simple div element) inside of that 2D array. I've tried using indexOf, but even tho it's placed inside an onclick function, always returns 0.

The html code contains just of few div's with col classes: 
[image]

And here is the JavaScript code (btw it contains some unnecessary stuff that I've just added for test purposes) :

```
let row = document.querySelector('.row');
let fields = document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-2')
let fieldsArr = Array.from(fields);
let header = document.getElementById("clicked");
let cols = header.getElementsByClassName("col-md-2");
let player = document.getElementById('player');
let player2 = document.getElementById('player2');
let blockedField = document.getElementsByClassName('blocked');

fieldsArr.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).forEach(function(el) {

  row.appendChild(el);
});

// ADD AN EVENT LISTENER AND LISTEN FOR COLS ID
function replyClick(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (e.nodeName === 'DIV') {
    let changable = e.id;
    //console.log(changable);
  }
}
// CREATE A 2D ARRAY (MAP)
var map = [];
while (fieldsArr.length) map.push(fieldsArr.splice(0, 6));

// ON CLICK ADD A CLASS OF ACTIVE
for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
  cols[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}

// MOVE PLAYER ONE ACROSS THE MAP
function movePlayer(multWidth, multHeight) {
  $(".active").append(player);
  if ((row).click > multWidth) {
    alert(1)
  }

}

// MOVE PLAYER 2 ACROSS THE MAP
function movePlayer2() {
  $(".active").append(player2);
}

// MAKE GRAYED OUT FIELD UNAVALIABLE AND SHOW AN ALERT
$(blockedField).css("pointer-events", "none");

// APPEND PLAYER1(2) TO THE FIRST(LAST) FIELD ON THE MAP
map[0][0].appendChild(player);
map[5][5].appendChild(player2);

// GET PLAYERS CURRENT POSITION
$(row).click(function() {
  let current = player.offsetTop; 
});

const widthAllowed = 3 * 156;
const heightAllowed = 3 * 146;

// LIMIT PLAYER MOVES
let player1Moves = 3;
player2Moves = 3;

$(row).click(function() {
  movePlayer();
  let remainingMoves = player1Moves -= 1;
  if (remainingMoves === 0) {
    alert("You don't have any more moves. Player's 2 turn.");
    $(player).css("pointer-events", "none");

    $(row).click(movePlayer2);
  }
})

for (var x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
    console.log(x, y);

  }
}

console.log(map);
console.log(map[2][5]);
console.log(map[5][0]);
```

Comment: Maybe just use an array of objects instead of a &quot;2d array&quot;.

Comment: And how would I do that? I just have to say that I'm fairly new to javascript.

Comment: try to separate UI of a game from the game logic. think what data structures you need to hold and process the data.. indexOf() should do the trick, just apply it on the correct list

Comment: Aaaand when I try to return the index of the player on the map it returns -1. 
console.log(map.indexOf(player));
// Outputs -1

Comment: It will output -1 when it can't find something. Calling indexOf on map is going to look through each array and try and find something that matches player. None of these will match because player is not an array, I presume. Perhaps you could give us some information about what is held in the structure called map?

Comment: Well it's just an 2d array that is linked to all the divs on the html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take some beginner jquery/javascript course, since your question is very simple and you will find the whole programming thing way easier with a few basic concepts (like selectors, events and callbacks)

That said, here is a basic example of how to return the `div` element that contains the player element and how to use event attachment instead of inline events.

```js
let row = $('.row');

row.on('click', replyClick);

function replyClick(e) {
  var targetRow = $(e.target);
  $('.row > div.active').removeClass('active');
  targetRow.addClass('active');
  var player = $('.row div.player');
  alert(player.parent().attr('id'));
};
```

```css
.player {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.row > div {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.row > div.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="col1" class="col-md-2">
       <div class="player"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="col-md-2 blocked"></div>
    <div id="col3" class="col-md-2 active"></div>
    <div id="col4" class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I'm currently taking a javascript course on Udemy, but I'm struggling a bit tbh